Manually publishing events to Node.JS tracing channels
Node provides a Tracing Channel mechanism since version 19, as part of its diagnostics_channel module and async_hooks effort.
A tracing channel can be created like this:
import diagnostics_channel from "node:diagnostics_channel";

const channel = diagnostics_channel.tracingChannel("channel");

They are supposed to monitor the lifetime of an event: start, end, and possible errors.
Three functions are provided:

channel.traceSync(() => {...}, ...)
channel.tracePromise(...)
channel.traceCallback(...)

For these, you pass the function you want to execute as first argument (or callback function), and the module will run the function and publish the events appropriately.
Unfortunately, I'm in the case where I want to use the tracing channel around an async generator. And there's no way that I'm aware of to do return yield* channel.traceGenerator(...)
That leaves me with calling the start, end, error events manually:
channel.start.publish({call});
channel.asyncStart.publish({call});
channel.asyncEnd.publish({call, result?, error?});
channel.end.publish({call, result?, error?});
channel.error.publish({call, error});

My question is this: when using those functions directly, do I need to do anything to link the asyncEnd call to the asyncStart one? So internals can detect that a started call was ended, ...

Thanks the question, I was trying to replace async_hooks by tracing_channels. Events are sent only once, while async_hooks sent events for each async tasks created by the function.... maybe I am doing something wrong....

@CyrilG. the events work fine for me. I have const channel = diagnosticsChannel.tracingChannel("blabla"); and on one end do channel.start.publish(...), ... (taking care to send all 4 events each time) and the other end channel.subscribe({...}).
